# SQL Server : Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, ibm-infosphere

A month ago I created a job in IBM `DataStage`, in the job I did ETL into database target, the job success executed. But two days ago when I was testing the connection of my database target in IBM `DataStage`, suddenly it failed to connect. [This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwirw.png). I did not change the password of the database so I'm very confused why I failed to connect, I already look for [solutions](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/troubleshooting-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-login-failed-user/) and one solution says since its probably caused by the authentication and needs to be changed into SQL Server authentication, it requires SQL Server Management Studio (I'm not sure if the authentication is the problem because I never changed **any setting** ever since I created the database and the job . But with `DBeaver`, I still can access and manage my database. What's going on actually and how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe the password got changed?

Comment: Did you create the SQL login with the `CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON` option? Has it expired?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the DBA is the one who created the SQL login, i'm asking her right now